# Download error on http://pypi.python.org/simple/ReviewBoard/: timed out -- Some packages may not be found

Tags: easy-install, review-board

Well...

I was faced a problem when I try to install ReviewBoard....

Below is error message..
Is there a solution?

P.S. My network is under proxy.

$ sudo easy_install ReviewBoard
Searching for ReviewBoard
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/ReviewBoard/

Download error on http://pypi.python.org/simple/ReviewBoard/: timed out -- Some packages may not be found!

Reading //pypi.python.org/simple/ReviewBoard/

Download error on //pypi.python.org/simple/ReviewBoard/: timed out -- Some packages may not be found!

Couldn't find index page for 'ReviewBoard' (maybe misspelled?)

Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)

Reading //pypi.python.org/simple/

Download error on //pypi.python.org/simple/: timed out -- Some packages may not be found!

No local packages or download links found for ReviewBoard

error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('ReviewBoard')

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in your terminal before issuing the easy_install command

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://user:password@proxy.domain.com:port
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://user:password@proxy.domain.com:port
```